# Duplicated HTML elements inside <link rel="import"> tag

Tags: html, html-imports

When I use HTML import, I see this:

[image]

Does it mean that I still have *one* `html` element, *one* `head` and *one* `body`?

Or, instead of that, these elements have duplicated?

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <link rel="import" href="parts.html">
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]');
        var content = link.import;
        var el = content.querySelector('.foo');
        document.body.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
    </script>
</body>
```

**parts.html**

```
<div class="foo">
    <p>Foo</p>
</div>

<div class="bar">
    <p>Bar</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. I wouldn't worry too much about what the DOM tree looks like in the Inspector though. It looks like that with iframes as well.

Comment: @MrLister So, you mean that the shown DOM tree is not real? In that case, maybe you know some way to see the actual (real) DOM tree?

Comment: @maioman It's example (a bit simplified) from [HTML5Rocks article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/).

Comment: I need your help.
Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/q/66546478/14467588.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into your scenario (made this [fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/C8XqPB7nT1ekaZEatCyZ?p=preview));

basically through the `import` property you can include anything an .html file can contain (giving access to a detached .html source),

the resource is embedded in the browser like an iframe
(at least this is the way the chrome implementation makes the resource available - [not implemented in other major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports)).

So you still have  ONE html element, ONE head and ONE body ,  the embedded resource looks like an iframe ,and that's what you see in your dev-tools.